# Generic LINQ Select implementation

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, repository

I am trying to implement a generic select which i have used with the following structure in my Repository implementation

```
 public IEnumerable<TEntity> Populate(Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>> predicate)
    {
        return (IEnumerable<TEntity>) _objectSet.Select(predicate).AsEnumerable();
    }
```

This i am invoking from my business logic with

```
public IEnumerable<DTO.Category> Populatelist()
    {

        return _repository.Populate(predicate: category => new { category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName }).ToList();

    }
```

But the category which should behave as an object of BTO.Category is not behaving like that as for **CategoryID** and **CategoryName** its displaying **Cannot resolve the symbol**.

So am i doing things right or m missing out something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well found the solution...The signature should be

```
List<TResult> Populate<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> predicate);
```

The Implementation in the Repository Class

```
public List<TResult> Populate<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> source)
{
        return _objectSet.Select(source).ToList();
}
```

Now use this from the Business Logic For Eg-

```
public IDictionary<int,string> Populatelist( )
{

    var expectedResult =_repository.Populate(category => new {category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName}).ToList();

    return expectedResult.ToDictionary(c => c.CategoryID, c => c.CategoryName);

}
```

The problem was as the return type was anonymous so that was creating the problem when passing the value, now the return type is Tresult of list type so no casting error..

Answer (score -1):

You need to define generic arguments to be used inside a generic method:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Populate<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
```

and then, use it as following:

```
return _repository.Populate<DTO.Catrgory>(predicate: category => new { category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName }).ToList();
```

Comment: i don't know why it is displaying "Unable to convert expression type predicate: category => new { category.CategoryID, category.CategoryName } to return type <DTO.Category> any guess ?